# PHP Code will not validate

Tags: php, html, sql, if-statement

I am trying to edit a PHP IF statement however, there is a syntax issue according to this online validator:

```
http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
        if (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false) 
            {?><input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>          
            <?php } ?>
                <?php
        elseif (strpos($row['price'] != NULL && strpos($row['price']) != '0' && strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== true) 
            {?><input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>
            <?php } ?>
```

This is what I a trying to achieve:

If the "Caption" begins with the text "DIGITAL" then the add to cart button should be active.
If the "Caption does not begin with the text "DIGITAL" AND the "Price" is not NULL or 0 then the shopping cart button should be active. In all other instances, it should be INACTIVE.

Here is the full source code:

```
<?php include_once('admin/config/config.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('admin/libs/functions.php'); ?>
<?php $obj = new Functions(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="960.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/nivo-lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/nivo-lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".view-img").nivoLightbox();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/shoppingcart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/general.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="CENSORED Photography provides the best quality photography in the SENSORED Region. Whether you are looking for a photographer for a wedding, portrait, event or literally anything else, Let your story begin with SENSORED Photography. ">
<meta name="keywords" content="Photography, , Videography, , Photo, Portrait, Best">
<title>SENSORED Photography</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".item_size").change(function(){
            item_val = $(this).val();
            n = $(this).attr("custval");
            if(item_val != "" && item_val != null) {
                $("#s"+n).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("#s"+n).attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>


<!-- oncontextmenu="return false;"-->
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="container_12">
        <div id="sidebar" class="grid_3">
            <img src="images/sidebar_02.png" alt="sidebar"/>


                <ul>
                    <li class="home"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery" style="color:#AD6FC4;"><a href="gallery.php">GALLERY</a></li>
                 </ul>

             <p>© Copyright SENSORED 2013</p>

       </div><!--end sidebar-->
        <div id="content" class="grid_9">

            <div id="contact" class="grid_3 alpha push_6">
            </div><!--end contact-->

            <div id="shop_cart">
                <span class="shop_cart_quantity"></span> items 

                 <span class="totalfront"></span><span class="shop_cart_total"></span>

                 <a href="#" id="viewcart" class="viewcart">View Details</a>

                <a href="javascript:;" class="shop_cart_checkout">Checkout</a> 

                <a href="javascript:;" class="shop_cart_empty">Empty Cart</a>




            </div>

            <div id="cart_overview" style="background: #ffffff; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; display: none">
                <div id="cart_overviewitems" class="shop_cart_items"></div>
                <div style="clear:left"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="action_overview" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; display: none">
                <!-- Product Added -->
                <div style="clear:left"></div>
            </div>


             <div id="content2" class="omega grid_9 content2 newpages">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat']!= NULL): ?>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id={$_GET['cat']}";
                    $data = $obj->select($query);
                ?>
                <h1 class="normalh1 newpagesnew"><?php echo strtoupper($data['name']); ?></h1>

                <?php
                    if($data['protected'] == '1'):
                ?>
                <?php
                    $cid = $_GET['cat'];
                    $cookName = "cat".$cid;

                    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookName]) || $_COOKIE[$cookName] != "checked"):
                ?>

                <div id="formWrap">
                    <form action="category-login.php" method="post" id="category_login">
                        <?php if(isset($_GET['mess']) && $_GET['mess'] == "err"): ?>
                        <p>Incorrect Password. Please try again.</p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <p>This gallery is protected. Please enter the password.</p>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?echo $cid; ?>" />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input">
                                <input type="password" id="password" class="detail" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                            </div><!-- end .input -->
                        </div><!-- end .row -->

                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="login"/>
                        </div><!-- end .submit -->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = {$_GET['cat']} ORDER BY id DESC";

                    $res = $obj->selectAll($sql);

                    if($res):
                ?>
                <?php $flag = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach($res as $dat): ?>
                <div class="grid_2 gal product">
                    <a href="viewgallery.php?cat=<?php echo $dat['id']; ?>">
                    <?php
                        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category_id={$dat['id']} AND cover=1";
                        $dat1 = $obj->select($sql1);
                        if($dat1):
                    ?>
                        <img src="gal/thumbs/<?php echo $dat1['filename']; ?>" />
                    <?php else:?>
                    <img src="images/nopic.png" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                    <span>
                    <a href="viewgallery.php?cat=<?php echo $dat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $dat['name']; ?>
                    </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($flag == 1): ?>
                <hr />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                    $n=1;
                    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category_id={$data['id']} ORDER BY id DESC";
                    $result = $obj->selectAll($query1);
                    if($result):
                ?>
                <?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
                <div class="grid_2 gal product">
                    <div class="product_item">
                    <a class="view-img" href="gal/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" <?php echo $row['caption'] != NULL ? 'title="'.$row['caption'].'"' : ''; ?>>
                    <img src="gal/thumbs/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>">
                    </a>
                    <span class="item_name" style="display:none">Photo <?php echo $data['id']."-".$row['id']; ?></span>
                    <?php if($row['price'] != NULL && $row['price'] != '0'): ?><span style="margin-bottom: 0">Price: <i class="item_price"><?php echo $row['priceunit'].$row['price']; ?></i></span> <?php endif; ?>
                    <input type="hidden" class="item_quantity" value="1" style="width:20px;">
                    <?php if($row['price'] != NULL && $row['price'] != '0'): ?>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sizes";
                        $res = $obj->selectAll($sql);
                    ?>
                    <select name="item_size" class="item_size" custval="<?php echo $n; ?>" required>
                        <option value="">Select Size</option>
                    <?php foreach($res as $line): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $line['width'].' x '.$line['height']; ?>"><?php echo $line['width'].' x '.$line['height']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart" disabled />
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div style="height:100px; float: left; clear:both"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $n++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php if($flag != 1): ?>
                No Image avilable.
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = {$_GET['cat']} ORDER BY id DESC";

                    $res = $obj->selectAll($sql);

                    if($res):
                ?>
                <?php $flag = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach($res as $dat): ?>
                <div class="grid_2 gal product">
                    <a href="viewgallery.php?cat=<?php echo $dat['id']; ?>">
                    <?php
                        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category_id={$dat['id']} AND cover=1";
                        $dat1 = $obj->select($sql1);
                        if($dat1):
                    ?>
                        <img src="gal/thumbs/<?php echo $dat1['filename']; ?>" />
                    <?php else:?>
                    <img src="images/nopic.png" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                    <span>
                    <a href="viewgallery.php?cat=<?php echo $dat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $dat['name']; ?>
                    </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($flag == 1): ?>
                <hr />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                    $n=1;
                    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category_id={$data['id']} ORDER BY id DESC";
                    $result = $obj->selectAll($query1);
                    if($result):
                ?>
                <?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
                <div class="grid_2 gal product">
                    <div class="product_item">
                    <a class="view-img" href="gal/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" <?php echo $row['caption'] != NULL ? 'title="'.$row['caption'].'"' : ''; ?>>
                    <img src="gal/thumbs/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>">
                    </a>
                    <span class="item_name" style="display:none">Photo <?php echo $data['id']."-".$row['id']; ?></span>
                    <?php if($row['price'] != NULL && $row['price'] != '0'): ?><span style="margin-bottom: 0">Price: <i class="item_price"><?php echo $row['priceunit'].$row['price']; ?></i></span> <?php endif; ?>
                    <input type="hidden" class="item_quantity" value="1" style="width:20px;">
                    <?php if($row['price'] != NULL && $row['price'] != '0'): ?>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sizes";
                        $res = $obj->selectAll($sql);
                    ?>
                    <select name="item_size" class="item_size" custval="<?php echo $n; ?>" required <?php if (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false) {?>disabled="disabled"<?php }?>>
                        <option value="">Select Size</option>
                    <?php foreach($res as $line): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $line['width'].' x '.$line['height']; ?>"><?php echo $line['width'].' x '.$line['height']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php 
        if (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false) 
            {?><input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>          
            <?php } ?>
                <?php
        elseif (strpos($row['price'] != NULL && strpos($row['price']) != '0' && strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== true) 
            {?><input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>
            <?php } ?>




             <?php else: ?>
                    <div style="height:100px; float: left; clear:both"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $n++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php if($flag != 1): ?>
                No Image avilable.
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php else: ?><!-- post -->
                <h1 class="normalh1">Invalid action.</h1>
                <?php endif;?>

            </div><!--end content2-->

        </div><!--end content--> 

    </div><!--end wrapper-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/docevents.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- Localized -->
```

Can someone advise why I cannot get my code to validate? it looks fine to me.
The validator states " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "{" in CODE on line 271.
Error Parsing CODE"

The code returns 500 Internal server error if I run it.

Comment: And the syntax validation error is... ?

Comment: Does the code actually run? Does it report an error?

Comment: BTW It's not necessary to wrap _every_ line in <?php...?>. You only need the tags once before a block of contiguous PHP code, and again after it.

Comment: Check your web server error logs for the cause of the 500 error response

Comment: Ok, the error is in your `elseif` condition; you have unclosed parentheses and you are omitting the second argument from `strpos`

Comment: (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false) should be (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') != false)

Comment: @sanki Absolutely not. See http://php.net/manual/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your `elseif` condition

```
(strpos($row['price'] != NULL && strpos($row['price']) != '0' && strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== true)
                     ^^                              ^ 
                     |missing ")"                    missing 2nd argument
                     missing 2nd argument
```

I can't even tell what you're trying to do here. Also, `strpos` will **never** return boolean `true` so your check at the end of this line will never be successful.

I would also suggest using PHP's [alternative syntax for control structure](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) when mixing PHP and HTML. Something like this...

```
<?php if (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false) : ?>
    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?= $n ?>" value="Add to cart"/>
<?php elseif (/* some other logic */) : ?>
    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?= $n ?>" value="Add to cart"/>
    <!-- this line is exactly the same as the previous one?!? -->
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can check below code in http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/ url for validation and get "No syntax errors detected in CODE" message.**

***You can use this code instead of your code definitely work.***

```
<?php if (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false){ ?>
    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>          
<?php } elseif ($row['price'] != NULL && $row['price'] != '0' && strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== true) {?>
    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This got the code to work:

```
<?php if (strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== false){ ?>
                    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>          
                    <?php }
                    elseif ($row['price'] != NULL && $row['price'] != '0' && strpos($row['caption'],'DIGITAL') !== true) {?>
                    <input type="button" class="item_add" id="s<?php echo $n; ?>" value="Add to cart"/>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div style="height:100px; float: left; clear:both"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```